# How to handle a change in different text input fields of the same form using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-fullstack

I have a form containing two fields of input; name and mark

I want to update a property depending on which field is changing, instead of making two (will be increasing) functions to handle each field individually.

Here is the current code which only updates the `name` property with the value:

```
    handleStudentChange(e) {
        console.log(e.target)
        var value = e.target.value
        console.log("value: ", value)
        var field = e.target
        //e.target returns <input id="mark1" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Mark 1" value="40">

        this.setState({
            activeStudent: {
                ...this.state.activeStudent,
                name: value
            }
        })
    }
```

Field can take the value of the target property name such as `name` or `mark1` by tapping into the `e.target.id` property. Is there a way to cast `field` as the property to use field:value or any other better way of going about the whole thing? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
handleChange = (e) => {
   const { name, value } = e.target;
   this.setState({ ...activeStudent, [name]: value });
};
```

the important thing to use this approach, you should have input `name` prop set as the state property. for example, if `activeStudent` has "name" property, corresponding input should be set

```
          <input
                value={this.state.activeStudent.name}
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="text"
                // this is important part
                name="name"
                id="name"
                     
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a attribute for key value.

```
<input id="mark1" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Mark 1" value="40" key="mark" />
<input id="name1" class="form-control" placeholder="Name 1" value="Test Name" key="name" />
```

Then you can get that attribute by calling *e.target.getAttribute('key')*.

```
handleStudentChange(e) {
    var value = e.target.value
    var key = e.target.getAttribute('key')

    this.setState({
        activeStudent: {
            ...this.state.activeStudent,
            [key]: value
        }
    })
}
```